Publishing alone may be counterproductive?
I am a (hopefully) soon-to-be PhD graduate, and by the time I graduate I should have 4 papers, 3 of them with only me as the only author and another one in collaboration with other people. I recently had an idea that I want to turn in a paper, and I am quite confident that I can do that on my own, maybe with some advice from the supervisor but I already have a quite clear idea of what I need to do in mind. My question is: can this be counterproductive?
I'll try to explain myself. If I end up with 4 out of 5 papers with me as the single author, I fear I'll be seen as someone who cannot collaborate with people, while in truth it just happened that I managed to prove most of the results I was interested in essentially by myself. Is this fear reasonable or am I worrying too much? How do you suggest me to proceed?

Don't worry. I'm the sole author on most of my papers and I am doing fine. I have never received a warning  along the lines you have suggested. Concentrate on your work, collaborate when  that make sense and do the best work you can do.

I was in the same situation after my PhD (which wasn't too long ago). In my experience, you will have plenty of time to collaborate during your postdoc. It is much more important that your research is good. One important thing that the (right) coauthor can contribute is the affirmation that you are working on something that is interesting to people other than you.

The current culture is this. If $8$ people write a joint annals paper, then they each get an annals paper (for jobs, awards, etc.). I think this is stupid.

@mathworker21, yes, almost any "metric" supposedly measuring the value of someone's work is silly... game-able by those interested... but/and surely admired by administrators, since "everything is much clearer then". :)

I've actually heard varied opinions about how to count papers (or whether to count them!). Without opening this can of worms, the two options seem to be "divide by the number of coauthors" or "just count the number". Besides metrics, it can also be quite rewarding to share your ideas with others, because of the supposed "80/20 rule" that 80% of your time is spent on 20% of the details. A coauthor may exactly cover your weaknesses and allow you to finish the project a lot faster. (P.S. This is also advice to myself, as I also predominantly write single-authored papers.)

As someone with a fairly varied profile between single-author and collaborated works, and also having served on a hiring committee recently, I will say that a balance is quite favourable. Too many collaborated papers and it seems like you can't work on your own, and too many solo papers seem like you might not get along with others. Neither are fatal, and if your work is good then this will be a non-issue.

Here's a different angle. You generally shouldn't publish everything you can prove. It takes a lot of time and resources to publish something, so there's a huge opportunity cost to pay. If your new idea will result in a genuinely good paper, great, go for it. A virtue of coauthors is that they ensure other people care about the results.

@mathworker21, why is it stupid? I think it's doubtful that being one of 8 co-authors is 1/8 the work of writing one paper. What do we gain by discounting someone's work (in the literal sense of applying a discount, not completely disregarding) because they found people whose ideas well complement their own? It seems as productive to discount work based on the number of references.

@LSpice Sometimes I have been lucky to have collaborations in which each coauthor does an approximately equal share. But it seems very common to wind up in collaborations in which everyone contributes at the start, gets through the easy parts, and then the project gets stalled at some hard part, and the only way the project gets finished is for one coauthor to give up on the prospect of their collaborators putting in the hard work, and simply do the hard parts and write the paper. The psychology of sole-authored papers is also different: more risk of looking foolish if you get something wrong.

Gentle reminder that comments should be used only to request clarifications and make suggestions to improve the question. If you address the main question, please use the answer box below. Especially for observations that might start a discussion: comments do not have threads, and they are complicated to follow.

@user509184 Do you favor some of the alternative possibilities, such as the Percentage-based Author Contribution Index?

According to my experience (50 years in academia) it works in just the opposite way. A PhD whose all papers are joint with her adviser raises a suspicion that she cannot work independently. It is good for your career to have single-authored papers.

I think the question is about co-authorship with other people, not the advisor. Perhaps the OP can clarify.

I would think it works, though not as pronouncedly, for other co-authors, too: some collaboration record is surely a good thing, but very few single-author papers leaves a  hiring committee in less of a position to judge the applicant's individual mathematical contributions (beyond the non-negligible ability to find/create, and work productively with, good teams).

Yeah, I meant with other people!
